# Jenkins discover my github repositories automatically

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, devops

I want to discover my scm (github) repositories automatically by Jenkins. Is there a plugin or other way to make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about the requirement, you are talking about. We can always set up webhook in our GIT repo and link that to jenkins job. When ever you make any commit in GIT repo, that will trigger jenkins job automatically.

Comment: When I create a new repository on github, jenkins can create the job automatically referencing the created repository.